# AWS CloudFormation Parameter values specified for a template which does not require them

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I porting code from ruby to Python for CloudFormation stack creation projects. Below is a stack that I just keep getting 'Parameter values specified for a template which does not require them.'

This really doesn't tell me anything.

I have checked the json against the schemas and all was ok, and checked against the stack created by the original code and it matches, so can someone see an issue here, or at least point me in the right direction.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "EcsStack-5ad0c44afbf508d0b5a158df0da307fca33f5f63",
    "Outputs": {
        "marc1EcsCluster": {
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "marc1EcsCluster"
            }
        },
        "marc1EcsClusterArn": {
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "marc1EcsCluster",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Parameter": {
        "Vpc": {
            "Description": "VPC ID",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "CloudFormationDummyResource": {
            "Metadata": {
                "Comment": "Resource to update stack even if there are no changes",
                "GitCommitHash": "5ad0c44afbf508d0b5a158df0da307fca33f5f63"
            },
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle"
        },
        "marc1EcsCluster": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster"
        }
    },
    "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"
}
```

Comment: There is no template property called "Parameter" . Please use "Parameters" instead.

Comment: Thx. I spent ages looking at this before I saw that

Answer (score 2):

As more general advice, the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) will catch these errors with messages like:

`E1001: Top level item Parameter isn't valid
template.json:19`